# Putting Column inside a Row in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a `Row`. Inside that `Row` there is a `ListView` and an `Image`.

I want to put the `Image` in a `Column` so that I can put a `SizedBox` on the top of it to push it down.
**I also have to align it to the bottom right side.**

Problem is since I have put the `Image` in the `Column` ---- **now nothing is visible**.

```
                                         Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[  
                                            Flexible(                                        
                                              child: 
                                              ListView.builder
                                              (
                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                                itemCount: bulletList[Index].length,

                                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) 
                                                {
                                                  return new ListView
                                                            (
                                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                                              children: <Widget>
                                                              [                                                      
                                                                ListTile(
                                                                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                                                                              radius: 6.0,
                                                                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                                                            ),
                                                                    title : Text(bulletList[Index][Index], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25,),)
                                                                ),
                                                              ]
                                                            );
                                                },                                          
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            
                                            Column(
                                              children: <Widget>[ 
                                                SizedBox( height: 2,),
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: 
                                                    GestureDetector(
                                                      child: Image(
                                                              //alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                                              image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
                                                              height: 15,
                                                              width: 15,
                                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                            ),
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                          ),
                                      
                                        ],
                                      ),
```

Comment: I recommend you to just focus on learning flutter for now and try to understand the theory and core concepts of flutter instead of directly working practically on a project. sorry for the harsh words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) instead of `Column` with `SizedBox` and set its `alignment` property to `Alignment.bottomRight`:

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: GestureDetector(
    child: Image(
      image: NetworkImage(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg',
      ),
      height: 15,
      width: 15,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```